# Get URL string parameters with PHP

Tags: php, parameters

I have in the adressbar the url `phpexample.com/go.php?https://www.phpezzz.com/community/article1.html`.
How do I extract from go.php file the `www.phpezzz.com/community/article1.html` part? This is, **without assigning the url to a variable in query string.**

Currently I use `go.php?m=https://www.phpezzz.com/community/article1.html` and extract the link with `$m = $_GET['m'];`, but I don't want to use `m=` in the URL.

Comment: I wanted to say without to use "m="

Comment: does that mean you would still like to edit your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to get the whole string.